# nivo slider image is not loading in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, nivo-slider

I added nivo slider into my drupal 7 site using views nivo slider module. I followed the step in this page  http://boroniatechnologies.com/installing-and-configuring-views-nivo-slider-in-drupal-7/. It worked .
Then I tried to create another slider , by creating a new view and new content type(following same method). But this time the images are not loading.When I opened the fire bug it showed that the image name is missing in the img src path.can any one tell me why the name of image is missing